# Bokeh cannot change datetime axis format

Tags: pandas, datetime, bokeh

I'm following different codes for how to display different datetime formats on the x axis but for some reason the axis is always in the format `mmmyy` like `Jan17`, no matter what I put into `DatetimeTickFormatter`. How can I change the format, for example `Jan 15, 2017`?

```
    p=figure(plot_width=800,plot_height=500)
    p.line(x="ENTRYDATE",y="Transactions",color='LightSlateGrey', source=sourceDay)
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation=1.5
    p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days=["%a\n%d %b"])
```

The `ColumnDataSource` is in the form:

```
ENTRYDATE | Transactions
2017-01-15  29
2017-01-20  30
..
2018-01-03  1
```

Where `ENTRYDATE` is a `datetime` object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have trouble reproducing your problem. For me, the following example based on your code works:

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
    from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
    import bokeh.io as bkio
    import datetime as dt

    date1 = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 15)
    date2 = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 20)

    sourceDay = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ENTRYDATE=[date1, date2], Transactions = [1, 2]))

    p=figure(plot_width=800,plot_height=500)
    p.line(x="ENTRYDATE",y="Transactions",color='LightSlateGrey', source=sourceDay)
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation=1.5
    p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days=["%b %d, %Y"])

    bkio.show(p)
```

Are you sure about the datetime-object in the ENTRYDATE-column of your data source?